# Mapping a texture to a mayavi mesh

Tags: python, numpy, visualization, texture-mapping, mayavi

I'm using mayavi in python to visualize some data. I have a surface in 3D space and I want to map an image to it. I have looked at mayavi documentation and all I could find was [this](http://github.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html?highlight=texture#texture-mapping-actors), which really doesn't help me much. Has anybody done something like this before?

Comment: I have actually been able to acheive this in matplotlib, though with a very bad frame rate...
Following the official examples for `Axes3D.plot_surface()`, simply set the keyword `facecolors` equal to your desired texture. I don't remember whether I tested it in RGB but it works in grayscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the `mesh` function actually does take a `scalars` argument, which then colors the corresponding point on the surface in accordance to the chosen colormap. I still however don't know how to map an arbitrary RGB image to the surface.

Comment: Okay. Now I know what you want to do, but I'm not sure how to solve it. Can the `color` option of `surf` help you?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't saw the chapter "Python scripting for 3D plotting". There is a collection of the mayavi commands which can be used inside python. For example the section ["3D Plotting functions for numpy arrays"](http://github.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html#d-plotting-functions-for-numpy-arrays). If you follow the links you find some description about the functions and a small example for each of them.

For your case you should take `mesh` or `surf`. Both functions are kind of equal, but are different. For example the `surf` function is more a subfunction of `mesh`, which is my opinion. You don't really have to define x and y-coordinates, you just need the z-coordinates in a 2D array. If you want to use `mesh` you have to pass all three coordinates (x,y,z) as 2D arrays.

I would suggest to check the examples.

Is this an answer to your question? Maybe you should be more specific about what you want to do.

Have a nice day and Happy Holidays.

Comment: Yes, I did see that. It turns out that it is poorly written. I guess you saw that too, as you are also unable to answer my question.